# How to concate two XML attributes in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave

How to concatenate two `XML` attributes in DataWeave from list output?

My payload is:

```
[{productDetails={ean=null, variation-attribute-id=Colour, attribute-id=Colour, 
attribute=System Value, varaints=123, display-name=Colour}]
```

I want an output like:

```
<variation-attribute variation-attribute-id="Colour" attribute-id="Colour">
```

I tried using the `++` operator but it's giving error like string to object.

Comment: output required is like    <variation-attribute variation-attribute-id="Colour" attribute-id="Colour">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you'll have to write something like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
variations: {
  (payload map {
    variation-attribute @(
      variation-attribute-id: $.productDetails.variation-attribute-id, 
      attribute-id: $.productDetails.attribute-id): ""
  }) 
}
```

(I'm assuming a `variations` element for the root)

Here, for each item in your list (`payload`) you have to generate a `variation-attribute` so you need a `map` operation.

Attributes are specified like this:

```
<element> @(<attrName>: <attrValue>, <attrName2>: <attrValue2>, ...)
```

The parenthesis surrounding `payload map ...` evaluates the enclosed expression and "fills" the value of `variations` with it's result (which is an array of `variation-attribute` elements)

Note: I put an empty string as text, since currently there's no way to close tags inline.